# Changing the color of a UIToolbar

Tags: ios, ios7, uitoolbar, tintcolor, bartintcolor

Why does the `UIToolBar` without setting a color in a modal view, have a default background color of light gray?

It is messing with my `barTintColor` and changing background isn't helping either.

How do I fix this?

Comment: you want to set tool bar tint color as same as the nav bar tint color ?

Comment: yes that is correct.  I see toolbar.barStyle but the black tint color on the nav bars aren't matching the toolbar ones. What is the default color for toolbars?

Comment: Tint color is made translucent by default unless you set the translucent property to NO.

Comment: and a very intresting thing u will know from this link...http://www.everydave.com/thoughts/?p=2426 please see this link too...

Comment: But when I set the tintColor in UIToolbar, it is different then the nav bar because the UIToolbar appears light Gray by default. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

UIToolbar also has a tintColor property, just like a UINavigationBar. You should be able to set one to the other:

So if you want to set the UINavigationBar tint color to the UIToolBar tint color then just

```
yourtoolbar.tintColor = yournavbar.tintColor;
```

At the end of your implementation file just write this.

UIToolbar with a color:

```
@implementation UIToolbar (UIToolbarCategory)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIColor *color = [UIColor WhiteColor];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents( [color CGColor]));
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
}
@end
```

hope it helps..

Comment: The problem is the uitoolbar default is gray instead of white. How do I make it white?

Comment: Or get rid of the default color?

Comment: see if you want your toolbar tintcolor as same as the navigation bar then above answer will work.. otherwise will update my answer